# Can i give the view a show up animation in emberjs

Tags: javascript, view, ember.js, router

Here is a example using emberjs router http://jsbin.com/agameq/edit.
Now I wanna have some showup animation, like fadeIn or fadeOut, when route changed. what should I do?

Comment: I've recently added a [project in GitHub](https://github.com/MilkyWayJoe/ember-router-with-webapi) as my own learning process, you might wanna take a look (it's still pretty rough but I'll be updating as I progress)

Comment: @MilkyWayJoe Ok, i will~ thanks~

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Every `View` in ember has a method named `didInsertElement`:

> Called when the element of the view has been inserted into the DOM.
>   Override this function to do any set up that requires an element in
>   the document body.

All ember views also have a `$` which is a reference to jQuery, so you can wrap some element in your view with it and apply any changes to it such as:

```
// this will animate only the tag h2, which in your case is the title of the users view
App.UsersView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: 'users',
    didInsertElement: function() {
        this.$('h2').animate({ fontSize: "3em" }, 900 );
    }   
});
```

Or you can call it without arguments (like `$()`) to return the current view wrapped by jQuery.

To animate a view as you enter in that view/route, do this in your `App.UsersView`:

```
// this will animate the entire view
App.UsersView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: 'users',
    didInsertElement: function() {
        this.$().animate({ fontSize: "3em" }, 900 );
    }   
});
```

(**Note**: my animation is pretty lame, but it's just to show where to call the methods, do a real animation)

Here's a modified version of [**your  JSBin**](http://jsbin.com/ehafoh/2/edit#javascript,html)

Comment: Thanks. Very interesting. I didn't know that Ember implemented the Cocoa-inspired didInsertElement. Is your example using jQuery.animate function? Meaning didInsertElement from Ember and then pass it to jQuery for UX stuff, right?

Comment: @nembleton That is correct, at that moment I'm calling the jQuery [`animate`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) function, because Ember already provides it to it's views, all you need to have is the script reference to jQuery

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your answser solved my big problems. I wanna use emberjs to do some webapp and the ux is really important for that. But right now the animation is using jQuery can the animation replaced by css3 tricks?

Comment: I wouldn't know *how* you can replace the jQ animations with CSS3 as I am not very familiar with the CSS3 transitions/etc or how to properly apply them. Still learning a bunch of things :)

Comment: OK, and i still have a question... For example, i have a function `load` in the controller which will load data from server. Now I want the view have a `fadeIn` animation when data loading finished. I want to get the `view` of the controller in `load` function like `this.get('view').fadeIn()`, how can i get the reference?

Comment: You should look into [`.observer`](http://jsfiddle.net/schawaska/WDW2v/) Run this with console active

Answer (score 5):

Following the answer from @MilkyWayJoe, you probably want to hide the View before inserting it, by setting the `isVisible` property to `false`:

```
App.UsersView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: 'users',

    isVisible: false,

    didInsertElement: function() {
        var self = this;
        this.$().fadeIn(700, function(){
            self.set('isVisible', true);  //inform observers of `isVisible`
        });
    }   
});
```

Or use [this animation Mixin](http://www.dynopia.com/en/blog/article/771/ember-js-animations-with-jquery-animate), which allows you to animate Views by changing a set of observed CSS properties:

```
App.UsersView = Ember.View.extend( JQ.Animate, {
    templateName: 'users',

    isVisible: false,

    // Observed CSS properties
    cssProperties: ['display'],

    // Optional animation properties
    duration: 700,
    easing: 'easeInOutCubic', 

    didInsertElement: function() {
        this.set('display', 'block'); 
    },

    afterAnimate: function() {
        this.set('isVisible', true);
    }   
});
```

Comment: Oh, that's nice. I will read the article and have a try. How can you get to know this info, by reading the source code?

Comment: The source code found [here](http://cloud.github.com/downloads/emberjs/ember.js/ember-latest.js) (which is the latest) has all the comments as opposed to the [documentation](http://emberjs.com/documentation/) which hasn't been fully updated (because most of the efforts are concentrated in the [1.0 milestone](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues?labels=&milestone=1&page=1&state=open)). I also suggest to [Google for "Ember Gist"](https://www.google.ca/#hl=en&q=ember+gist) and you'll get several great resources.

Comment: Hi, how can i access dom elements in controller... For example, i load some elements in controller and i need to resize the width of elements' parent. How can i get the parent dom and set its width in controller?