# Ember - Handling clicks outside of view

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

Wondering if anyone has come up with a better way for handling a click outside a div while using Ember? I know of the jQuery way with a global click handler that you must specify each action to take for certain instances, but am hoping someone has come up with a way to declare this inside an Ember view. As well, I tried the ol' give a div a tab index and use the on blur, but Ember actions don't seem to allow this.

Comment: I don't understand what the issue is. You can delegate the event based on a regexp expression, this doesn't require anything crazy. Even taking a look at the Ember.js documentation states that leveraging jQuery's `.on()` method is the approach they use to solving delegation issues along large subsets of elements, nested or not.

Comment: You can use the [`didInsertElement`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11377215/can-i-give-the-view-a-show-up-animation-in-emberjs/11377899#11377899) event to start up a plug-in and things like that. And you should use [`willDestroyElement`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.View.html#event_willDestroyElement) to remove bindings. Alternatively you can use [`View#on`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.View.html#method_on).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks for the input. I went back and read the documentation on jQuerys `.on` again. I was not aware that you could namespace the event. So I took both of the comments and combined them with something like this.

```
didInsertElement: function() {
    Ember.run.next(this, 'attachClickHandler');
},

attachClickHandler: function (){
    var temp = this;

    $(window).on("click." + temp.elementId, function (e){
        //...event here
    });
},

detachClickHandler: function (){
    $(window).off("click." + this.elementId);
},
```

This allows for the event to be specific for each view instance, which is what I was wanting. Thanks guys!

Comment: I'm assuming the `detachClickHandler()` is called from the view's `willDestroyElement` hook?

Comment: I did not know about the event namespacing :)

Answer (score 2):

you may find [ClickElsewhereMixin](https://gist.github.com/stevekane/6356006) useful

just include the mixin on any component and implement onClickElsewhere()